# SFTP curl error : curl: (1) Protocol http not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: curl, sftp

I am trying to use curl sftp to upload a file to a server. sftp used is through key based authentication.Here is the command.

```
sudo curl -v -u nodebsecadmin: --key /data/ssh/externalLogUserKey --pubkey /data/ssh/externalLogUserKey.pub --ftp-create-dirs -k -T extlog_test.txt sftp:"http://www.iprc.lucent.com/~prcm/junk/extlog_test.txt"
```

I am getting the error :

```
curl: (1) Protocol http not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

i tried using single quotes as well suggested in different forums, but it didnt work.

current curl version supports SFTP.

```
eCCM-nodebsecadmin-/store> curl -V
curl 7.30.0 (powerpc-wrs-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.30.0 OpenSSL/1.0.0 zlib/1.2.5 libidn/0.6.5 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: file ftp ftps scp sftp
Features: IDN SSL libz
```

what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when your URL is corrupt. This usually occurs when something is before the `http`. What is the purpose of the prefix `sftp:` . That looks wrong. Use `sftp` or `http` but not both.

Answer (score 0):

You get that warning because you use a HTTP URL with a libcurl that clearly was built without HTTP support - that's a non-standard libcurl build.

The URL you use has the wrong syntax (seemingly trying to be both HTTP and SFTP at the same time). Try something like this instead if you really want an SFTP URL:
`sftp://www.iprc.lucent.com/~prcm/junk/extlog_test.txt`